# many to many field omitted in database table when running syncdn

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a field with M2M relationship.when running syncdb,the field with M2M field does not form on the database.
here is the model

```
class Eventgroups(models.Model):
    event=models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    group_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s,  %s" \
            % (self.group_name, self.event)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'eventgroup'
        verbose_name_plural='eventgroups'
```

events field is not created on database
I would appreciate an insight to this problem please
Regards,
Joshua

Comment: model definition seems fine. How do you know it's not being created?

Comment: I have opened the database,table Eventgroups has two fields, id(the default by django) and group_name

Comment: You realize ManyToMany is not actually a field, right?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok. You just don't understand how ManyToMany is realized on the SQL level. Simply speaking, this

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    #...

class Bar(models.Model):
   foo = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

is technically the same as this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    #...

class Bar(models.Model):
    #...

class BarFoo(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

And if you'll check your database - you will find a table called EventgroupsEvent or something like that which contains the actual fields. It's just the ORM that lets you connect the models directly. Please [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644725/2387772) for a detailed explanation on how ManyToMany works in the background

Answer (score 0):

It wont create a field named event instead, it will create a new table **Eventgroups_event**