# django OnetoOneField in database

Tags: django

how one-to-one field in django reflected in database?
I have two model: Neighbor and Neighbor_Info which has one-to-one field connection to Neighbor.

But In the database I don't see any reference field relation between this two table
[image]

[image]

So I wonder how the one-to-one relation reflected on database?
(I use postgresql)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but this linked question may provide additional insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641841/django-difference-between-one-to-one-many-to-one-and-many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Neighbor_Info` model has a `OneToOneField` to `Neighbor`.

```
class Neighbor_Info(models.Model)
    neighbour = models.OneToOneField(Neighbor)
    ...
```

Therefore your `Neighbour_Info` database table has a column `neighbor_id`, which is pictured in your second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid but did you remember to migrate?

And secondly on your neighbor info table there is a neighbor_id which should reference reference the id of a neighbor on your neighbor table